# SQL to return preferred duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, duplication, teradata

Have a data set that some rows have a duplicate. Looking to return the row with IND = Y if it is present, otherwise to return the N.

```
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
| rollup_mth | SLS_OUTLET_ID | vacant_ind |          |
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 8/1/2018   |         97985 | N          | RSSTRAWS |
| 8/1/2018   |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 |
| 10/1/2018  |         97985 | N          | RSBRASIL |
| 11/1/2018  |         97985 | N          | RSBRASIL |
| 12/1/2018  |         97985 | N          | RSBRASIL |
| 12/1/2018  |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 |
| 1/1/2019   |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 |
| 2/1/2019   |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 |
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Is it sql-server, teradata or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER ordering by a CASE on `vacant_ind`WHEN 'Y' then 0:

```
WITH ct AS
(
SELECT
  rollup_mth, SLS_OUTLET_ID, vacant_ind, other,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rollup_mth, SLS_OUTLET_ID
                     ORDER BY CASE vacant_ind WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) RN
FROM
  t
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  ct
WHERE
  RN = 1;
```

> ```
> rollup_mth          | SLS_OUTLET_ID | vacant_ind | other    | RN
> :------------------ | ------------: | :--------- | :------- | :-
> 01/08/2018 00:00:00 |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 | 1 
> 01/10/2018 00:00:00 |         97985 | N          | RSBRASIL | 1 
> 01/11/2018 00:00:00 |         97985 | N          | RSBRASIL | 1 
> 01/12/2018 00:00:00 |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 | 1 
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 | 1 
> 01/02/2019 00:00:00 |         97985 | Y          | VSP97985 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=885316868bbb5c10f5335da5cc87a7c6)*

Answer (score 0):

Apply a ROW_NUMBER:

```
select *
from mytable
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by rollup_mth, SLS_OUTLET_ID
         order by vacant_ind desc) = 1
```

This assumes that `vacant_ind` has only `Y/N` values.